# OpenSSL problems using oAuth2 gem and facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ssl, oauth-2.0

So I've upgraded an app from rails 2.2 to 2.3.12 and my last remaining issue is the problem of facebook connect integration.

I am using the oauth2 gem for this and well I keep getting the following error

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):
```

I've tried to follow the descriptions on the oauth2 wiki page just to end up with anohter error that was solved by forking the project and adapting the code. [read here](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/issues/58).

I do not have the issue on my development server but only in production.

my client code looks as follows

```
def client  
  ca_file = File.join('/etc/ssl/cacert.pem')  
  @client ||= OAuth2::Client.new( 'app_id', 'app_secret', {  
    :site => {  
      :url=>'https://graph.facebook.com',  
      :ssl=>{  
        :verify => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER,  
        :ca_file => ca_file  
      }  
    },  
    :adapter => :NetHttp  
  })  
  @client  
end
```

I've confirmed about a hundred times now that my cacert.pem file is there and that
the rights are ok.

Any ideas on where to begin debugging are welcome.

Comment: what does `ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'` print on your development server and what does it say in production?

Comment: @emboss  

**Developement** OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009  

**Production** OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I moved this site on to a new server running Debian 6.0 (sqeeze) instead of 5.0 (etch) and this solved my problem. My take on this is that I got a newer version of OpenSSL:

Debian 6.0: OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
Debian 5.0: OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007

I can't guarantee that this was the issue but since it's now working with no code changes. I assume it is.